# Is there a way to convert flutter package to plugin?

Tags: flutter, plugins, package

I have a Package made a while ago but I want to add some Android specific code (Java, but this doesn't matter). The only approach I currently have is just creating a new Plugin and moving things around from the old package to the new plugin.

Is there another way I'm missing?
Maybe a command line prompt or another tool?

*Note for the differences between Package and Plugin from [flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages)*